# How can I combine histograms with a density plot in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, density-function, histogram

Starting with a really simple example, a bi-modal distribution, however, keeping in mind that this would likely be applied to more complex cases where modality is not as apparent, nor limited to 2 peaks. Albeit, this is the simple step.

`x <- c(1,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,5,2,4,2,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,3,5,4,5,4,7,5,4,4,3,2,1,2,4,3)`

`dx <- density(x)`

`plot(dx)`

Gives this plot:
[image: Simple example of bi modal density plot]

However, I would like to make a graph like the one that follows. However, my R is limited, I understand, par(mfrow=c(2,1)) would give me the over and under. But I have no idea how to calculate the values for the bottom graph. I like R and I would like to continue to use it, but my capabilities are limited.

[image: Crude paint version of what I would like.]

Answer (score 16):

Is this what you want?

```
x <- rep(c(2,8), c(20,10))

dx <- density(x, bw=1.8)
plot(dx, ylim=c( -max(dx$y)/3, max(dx$y)))

tmp.x <- dx$x[ c(TRUE, rep(FALSE,15)) ]
tmp.y <- dx$y[ c(TRUE, rep(FALSE,15)) ]
tmp.n <- length(tmp.x)

tmp.xx <- rowMeans( embed(tmp.x,2) )
tmp.yy <- rowMeans( embed(tmp.y,2) )


dy <- diff( tmp.y )
dy2 <- dy/max(abs(dy))

library(TeachingDemos)
my.symbols( tmp.xx, tmp.yy, ms.arrows, angle=pi/2, adj=0,
            inches=1, r=dy2, col=ifelse(dy2>0, 'green','red') )


ms.bar <- function(hgt,...) {
    cbind( c(-1,-1,1,1,-1)/4, c(0,hgt,hgt,0,0) )
}

tmp.in <- diff(grconvertX(tmp.xx[1:2], to='inches'))*4

my.symbols( tmp.xx, -max(dx$y)/6, ms.bar, hgt=dy2, inches=tmp.in, 
            col=ifelse(dy2>0, 'green','red') )
```

[image]

You could probably do it using the `arrows` and `rect` functions instead of `my.symbols`, but this seemed the simplest.

Comment: Impressive; I didn't understand the question at all, but you certainly seem to have answered it.